# Drupal Batch Forms - Process values?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

Is there a way to have a form send form values into a batch process and use them on each batch operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can just pass them through to the function that declares the batch, and from there pass them to each operation:

```
function mymodule_myform_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $var1 = $form_state['values']['var1'];
  $var2 = $form_state['values']['var2'];
  batch_set(mymodule_mybatch($var1, $var2));
}

function mymodule_mybatch($var1, $var2) {
  $nid = db_result(db_query_range("SELECT nid FROM {node} ORDER BY nid ASC", 0, 1));

  $operations = array();
  for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    $operations[] = array('mymodule_mybatch_op', array($nid, $var1, $var2));
  }
  $batch = array(
    'operations' => $operations,
    'finished' => 'mymodule_mybatch_finished',
  );
  return $batch;
}

function mymodule_mybatch_op($nid, $var1, $var2) {
  // Perform the operation
}

function mymodule_mybatch_finished($success, $results, $operations) {
  if ($success) {
    $message = count($results) . ' processed.';
  }
  else {
    $error_operation = reset($operations);
    $message = 'An error occurred while processing ' . $error_operation[0] . ' with arguments :' . print_r($error_operation[0], TRUE);
  }
  drupal_set_message($message);
}
```

Obviously you'd need to change where the data comes from in `mymodule_mybatch` to suit your needs :)